# Update all branches on forked repo with github.com?

Tags: github

I have a forked repo. The original repo has been updated and I need to pull in these changes. I would prefere to use github.com for this rather than the command line if possible.

From the github.com page of my fork I have a button called Compare which allows me to compare my branches with the branches in the original repo, and merge if there are changes. This should do what I want except that the changes I need to update are in a new branch that isn't in my repo.

Comment: You can create a Pull Request across two branches in seperate forks.  Follow the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best way to do this is by installing the [Pull](https://github.com/apps/pull) app in GitHub.

After forking a repository, you can then enable the app for the
repository, and then [configure](https://github.com/wei/pull#getting-started) the app for the forked repository.